# Retrofit how to handle two type responses?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an API server for an Android application.

I'm trying to use Retrofit for it.

The api server can return normal, say `/users`

```
{
    "userId":"123",
    "username":"John Doe"
}
```

but it might also return an error.

```
{
    "errorCode":0,
    "errorMessage":"blah"
}
```

So I'm just wondering, Is there a way to handle the errors globally for every method in Retrofit?

Edit:

I ended up with modifying server outpus.

```
{
    data:[],
    error:{}
}
```

Comment: out in two different objects or array. pack them togather.

Answer (score 1):

make method of api using JsonObject as shown below

```
 Call<JsonObject> listRes(@Body GsonRegisterUser user);
```

and now used

```
Call<JsonObject> call = listenerRegisterUser.listRes(gsonRegisterUser);
```

Now you will get json response by using following method and you can parse according to your requirement

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Response<JsonObject> response) {
            Log.e(TAG,response.body().toString());
    }
```